# How to monitor swap activity on desktop in real time (preferrably separately for each swap device)

Tags: command-line, kernel, swap

It would be informative to know in real-time the swap activity (number of reads and writes per minute or similar measure). I intend to use it with `conky`.

I can gather similar statistics by `vmstat` or agregate output of `iotop`. Unfortunately I cannot learn about the activity specifically on each swap device. The `swapon` command doesn't provide such answer and neither do `/proc/swaps`.

(I use zram swap, so the moment when swapping occurs is not immediately obvious. And since zram swap makes penalty for cpu I would like to know if it happens when I start long computations. )

Answer (score 2):

I had to google the answer but the tool you need would be vmstat, example usage:

```
vmstat 5
```

Would print out data with updates every 5 seconds, change the 5 to suit to get information on the meaning of the columns of data it prints take a look at the manual page.

```
man vmstat
```

In your case it is probably si and so which will be of interest si=swap-ins and so=swap-outs, you can also view some stats including some counters since boot with with -s option.

Comment: Thank you. +1 for your effort. Unfortunately, AFAIK it doesn't show the swap statistics separately for each device.